# Google maps + anchor scrolltop to div

Tags: jquery, google-maps, hover, scrolltop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make a hover or click event on a google maps marker scroll down a scrollable div. I've come this far:

[Example](http://www.mathieuserruys.com/coeur_catering_temp/locations/)

You can see that the scroll is obviously off. I cant seem to figure why this is happening. I've already tried to apply the scroll to the body and not make the whole fixed, but it does not fix the problem. Wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields is being used to easyly add locations, so adding ID etc is a bit hard as its php looping though markers, unless it would be with a `$i++` counter.

These are my scripts:

This code i've added in my Google maps api:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
liTag=$(".locations-item").find("[data-lat='" + $marker.attr('data-lat') + "']");
marker.setIcon(icon2);
this.setOptions({zIndex:10});
$(liTag).addClass('active');
$(".locations-item a").addClass('fade');
$('.gmap-scroll').animate({
         scrollTop: $(liTag).offset().top
 } );
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
liTag=$(".locations-item").find("[data-lat='" + $marker.attr('data-lat') + "']");
marker.setIcon(icon1);
  this.setOptions({zIndex:1});
$(liTag).removeClass('active');
$(".locations-item a").removeClass('fade');
});
```

Every Item has an A with lat and lng attributes, and in the google JS this gets a .find (see liTag). It finds every unique marker properly, as it highlight the divs and the markers just fine.

```
<div class="locations-item text-center">
<a data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
[IMAGE OF LOCATION]
</a>
</div>
```

Would appreciate the help greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.gmaps` div has `position:fixed` and that's why the browser thinks, that the `.row` div which contain the `.gmaps` div has 0 height, thus it thinks that scrolling is unnecessary.

To fix this, either make `.gmaps` div `position:static` or `position:relative` and adjust it's other css attributes, or assign some `height` to `.row` containing the `.gmaps` div.

So, for example use this CSS for `.gmaps` instead the one you have:

```
position: relative;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If the answer fixes your issue please accept/upvote it.